# Request Entity Too Large in Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

iam install wordpress in host
ican not upload plugin from mypc
 when upload plugin with size 700kb 
the show error 
Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/wp-admin/update.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
Apache/2.2.3Apache/2.2.3 at  domain  Port 80

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini file and restart apache.

Please see: 
[PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: i try not work becuse this my plugin smaller than  1M

Comment: have you created a dummy page pi.php that contains the following code 

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

Just to verify both of these settings are large enough.

Comment: i change php.ini upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M

Comment: Out of the box php should be able to handle a 1M file. I beleive the default limit is 2M. Why I am asking you to actually check what PHP thinks these settings are by doing a phpinfo(); and actually seeing what PHP registered for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. There are a number of ways these can be changed and I want to completely rule it out. These can be changed in php.ini, .htaccess, or in code. 

Are you running anything like Suhosin? If you are it also has a similar setting you may want to check.

Comment: this result after run php info  result in upload_max_filesize=100M and  post_max_size=100M  after change php.ini what Setting htaccess ?

Comment: @M.Ganji were you able to fix your problem? If you have not check to make sure this isn't an issue.

file_uploads = Off

Comment: Ichange wp-config.php    add this to top of wp-config.php
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');  Problem solved

Comment: Nice. You should answer your own question and accept your answer.